# execute sql files from a folder in postgres

Tags: postgresql, shell

I have a set of sql files placed in a folder in postgres docker image. Whenever a new account is created, I want a new database to be created and all these scripts should get executed on that new created database.

New database will be created manually. I need to create sh file to ask for db name, host, port, password etc and then execute all sql files on new created database.

I tried and I can execute one single file

```
psql -h localhost -d sampledb -U superuser -f sample.sql
```

I need to execute all files in the folder. How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can make use of small bash script.
Copy all your sql files to a folder, for example test.
Then execute the below line of script.

```bash
for i in $(ls -l test/*.sql |awk '{print $NF}'); do 
    psql -h localhost -d sampledb -U superuser -f $i; 
done
```